# Java Facebook Graph

Tags: java, facebook

I'm trying to fetch facebook user data through Java.

I have retrieved the cookie which facebook app stored but I'm unable to parse it correctly

This is the key:value pair

```
    20x1UNyx0N1vXguFIBk3jwTx8Z_8A6BFW9Xz4uwSmRA.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJhYTY2ZGZjNzA3YWE5ZGIyZTU1YTc1MDUuMS0xMDAwMDA3MDI4ODYwOTV8ZXJoanU1SGZEOE8ydEQ5OGFEdk04RWpoSHJNIiwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoxMzI0MDM0MzAwLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTAwMDAwNzAyODg2MDk1In0
```

According to Facebook Signed Request Docs I should base64 decode the key value pair separately but I'm getting Exception

com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException: It
should be divisible by four

This is the code:

```
String[] pairs = str.split("&");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String pair : pairs) {
        String[] kv = pair.split("\\.");
        try {
            map.put(new String(Base64.decode(StringUtils.replaceChars(kv[0],"-_","+/"))), new String(Base64.decode(StringUtils.replaceChars(kv[1],"-_","+/"))));
        } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    String signedRequest = (String) req.getParameter("signed_request");
    String payload = signedRequest.split("[.]", 2)[1];
    payload = payload.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/").trim();
    String jsonString = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(payload.getBytes()));

    // use the jsonString as you like.
}
```